# Mysql-Server 8 can't login as root user at initial setup - Can't change root password

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I'm encountering with this situation in Ubuntu 22. I tried mysql_secure_installation it says access denied. So I tried other methods such as - I stopped the mysql server then I created a text file with contents:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'NewPassword';
```

Then I ran this command:

```
mysqld --init-file=/home/me/mysql-init &
```

Then I tried to login with my new password, no luck. Another method is:

1. Stop mysql
2. Run `sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &`
3. Run  `mysql -u root`
4. FLUSH PRIVILEGES
5. ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'NewPassword';

I stuck at step 3 here. Can't connect, it says `'ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'`

So there was no mysqld directory in /var/run and I created it and made it's user 'mysql'. After that I can login and and run the 5th command above but it says '0 rows affected' and I can't login with my new password again.

I remember changing root password with the second method before. It's my initial setup and I just installed mysql-server. What's the problem here?

Comment: Might be simpler to uninstall MySQL and start again, taking more care to remember the password

Comment: It's my initial setup and it requires password and I tried reinstalling.

Comment: https://devanswers.co/how-to-reset-mysql-root-password-ubuntu/